# Setup Openvpn with mobile public IP

Tags: openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN server on Xubuntu virtual machine and my client is Fedora 33 virtual machine. My host machine and the above two VMs are connected to my mobile hotspot.
My Question is

1. how can I create a VPN tunnel using the public IP of my mobile?
2. How I can setup OpenVPN without public IP inside VirtualBox?

IP configurations:

Mobile : ISP provided public IP

Host: 192.168.43.26

Fedora 33 VM: 192.168.43.30

Xubuntu VM: 192.168.43.40

Comment: Setting up a VPN server requires your internet router (your hotspot in your case) to provide port forwarding from the public internet to the OpenVPN server. This is generally beyond the capability of mobile phones or other hotspots, which are only designed for client/outbound connection support. Does your hotspot provide port forwarding capabilities?

Comment: To access a device with changing IP address, use DDNS. As commented, the hotspot needs to port-forward to the OpenVPN server, whose IP address must be stable. Nothing particular needs to be done to set up the OpenVPN server.